# Trouble with custom libevent package while building hiphop

Tags: php, linux, cmake, libevent, hiphop

I'm having trouble building hiphop under Backtrack 5.  I have installed all the essentials and apparently the only part that it keeps failing at is the custom libevent package.

Here are the commands I'm running in order to build and install libevent.

```
wget http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz
tar -xzvf libevent-1.4.14b-stable.tar.gz
cd libevent-1.4.14b-stable
cp ../hiphop-php/src/third_party/libevent-1.4.14.fb-changes.diff .
patch -p1 < libevent-1.4.14.fb-changes.diff
./configure --prefix=$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
make
make install
```

When building libevent it builds and installs with no errors.  When attempting to build hiphop these are the commands I am running:

```
cd hiphop-php
git submodule init
git submodule update
cmake -D CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=`/bin/pwd`/../ .
```

However when running CMAKE I get this error:

```
CMake Error at CMake/HPHPFindLibs.cmake:65 (message):
Custom libevent is required with HipHop patches
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this problem or at least point me in the right direction?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention this, but every time I attempt to patch the libevent source I get this message:

```
patch -p1 < libevent-1.4.14.fb-changes.diff
patching file event.c
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
```

Here I usually just answer yes and allow it to proceed

Comment: Hiphop installation is very painful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem for a while.

Following the steps above surely installs the libevent correctly.

Although the site in not clear, this error may be caused by misdirecting the cmake path.

For example, I saved hiphop in the following path: /dev/, and the libevent in the path: /.
So, I had to set the following:

```
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/
```